# How do I reference the current url of a page within a script for dynamic pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been stuck on this question all day and night reading everything I could find on Stackoverflow. I didn't want to ask such a noob question but I can't find anything that works properly.

I'm simply trying to make this.page.url = the current url. It's a dynamic page so it needs to be automatically updated. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```html
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = 'window.location.href';
    this.page.identifier = 'window.location.href';
    };
    (function() {
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://zoomingintv.disqus.com/embed.js';
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put window.location.href inside quotes.

```js
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = window.location.href;
    this.page.identifier = window.location.href;
};

// Edit:
// Try reloading function whenever url is changed.

window.addEventListener('hashchange', ()=>disqus_config());
```

Comment: I tried this and the code works but every single comment box is the same. So when I comment on one post, every post gets the same comment.

Comment: @GeorgeWert I have edited the answer. Try that.

Comment: I am sorry to say this still didn't work. I'm using Wix if that matters. I don't think the windows.location.href works because it doesn't change colors like the rest of my code when I type it. I apologize, I am very new and simply trying to make something for a friend.

Comment: @GeorgeWert, you should always include a minimal reproducible example in question with every lines of code that might possibly have effected the result. Then I or anyone else could have helped. Your question was to reference current URL. Try to `console.log(this.page.url)` inside `disqus_config()`. If URL is updated whenever page updates, your question is solved. Try to debug other stuffs.